# Instruct locally emulated firebase function to use authentication emulator

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am using firebase emulator suite to test my app. I have set up emulators for hosting, authentication, firebase and functions.

When I try to create a user from front-end using `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` it works fine.

All other emulators work as expected too..

I am able to call a callable function from my front-end:

in public/app.js

```
const createUser = functions.httpsCallable('createUser');
createUser({
    username: username,
    email: email,
    password: password,
})
```

in functions/index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    // creates a new user
    return admin.auth().createUser({
        email: data.email,
        emailVerified: false,
        password: data.password,
        displayName: data.username,
        disabled: false
    });
});
```

This function gets called, however it does not create a user on the auth emulator, but in production.

I want my user to be created on the auth emulator, so that it can trigger auth functions in my functions/index.js

For example:

```
exports.userCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
    // creates a firestore document in users collection
    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
        email: user.displayName
    });
});
```

There does not seem to be anything about connecting Node.js Firebase SDK to the auth emulator (`admin.auth().useEmulator() is not defined`).

How do I go about instructing a Node Admin SDK to use local auth emulator?

Comment: Hi Nikola, I'm having the same issue with connecting the Node Admin SDK to the emulator... I'm curious if you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: I have the same issue, I want to fetch users from local auth emulator but it's trying to fetch from production.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I still haven't found a solution...

Comment: Can you try updating firebase and firebase-admin to the latest version? I solved the problem by updating and my auth requests started using the auth emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed @Vazgen answer, and I can confirm that update the firebase-admin to the latest version can fix it, version 9.9.0 as of this writing.

```
npm install firebase-admin@latest
```