# The Firebase Admin SDK Don't Connect to The Authentication emulator

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, admin, emulation, google-admin-sdk

the admin auth is connected to the firebase project auth, not to the emulator auth

when I list the users using  [this code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) the result is the users that are in the firebase deployed project, not the users that are in the emulator

I tried [this method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#admin_sdks)  and the result is the same and when I tried to change to project id in

```
admin.initializeApp({
projectId: "your-project-id"
});
```

this is the error shown

> errorInfo: {
> code: 'auth/insufficient-permission',
> message: 'Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property has insufficient permission to access the requested resource. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/adoogle.com/docs/admin/setup for details on how to authenticate this SDK with appropriate permissions.'
> },

Comment: [This](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/575#issuecomment-524744793) might be helpful

Comment: I tried this before and didn't work

Comment: In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65763383/instruct-locally-emulated-firebase-function-to-use-authentication-emulator), someone have successfully fetched users from local auth emulator on the comments. Try commenting on the post and ask [Vazgen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11579692/vazgen) or directly [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/11579692/vazgen) if Vazgen can help you. Vazgen solved the problem by updating firebase and firebase-admin to the latest version and the auth requests started using the auth emulator.

Comment: it worked by updating firebase-admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning was in the terminal

```
The Firebase Authentication emulator is running, but your 'firebase-admin' dependency is below version 9.3.0, so calls to Firebase Authentication will affect production.
```

so by updating firebase-admin to 9.8.0 it worked